# Django & Mongo ORM mapping

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, mongokit

I have a Django project with a MongoDB, connecting through pymongo.
I've looked into [several ORM(-like) layers](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/tools.html), but none of them seem well maintained or supporting the Django 1.8 (mongo-engine only supports Django 1.5, mongokit is no longer maintained, and the other libraries seem to have no real community behind them).

So I think I'll be just using pymongo, which means that there is quite some things I'll need to implement myself, for example validation (checking that every document inserted in a collection has the required fields and field types).
How would I go about this?
Are there any example projects that I can take a look at?

I found [this](https://github.com/mdirolf/DjanMon/blob/master/status/views.py) project which connects from Django directly to Mongo, but there is not much structure in it.

Comment: Is there a reason you dont want to use the original Django [ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/) directly with MongoDB using a backend connector like [djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)? You dont need to switch to any other 'ORM Like' layers to begin with!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PyMODM. As the docs you linked to say, "PyMODM is an ORM-like framework on top of PyMongo. PyMODM is maintained by engineers at MongoDB, Inc. and is quick to adopt new MongoDB features. PyMODM is a “core” ODM, meaning that it provides simple, extensible functionality that can be leveraged by other libraries to target platforms like Django. At the same time, PyMODM is powerful enough to be used for developing applications on its own. Complete documentation is available on readthedocs in addition to a Gitter channel for discussing the project."

https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/tools.html